# Reading large file from QNetworkReply to QFile? Streaming from QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qt

Whats the correct way to stream a large file from a `QNetworkReply` to a `QFile`, in a non-blocking fashion?

I assume I need to connect to `QNetworkReply::readyRead` signal and call `QNetworkReply::read` in the slot, and write the data with `QFile::write`, and then I guess in `QNetworkReply::finished` call `QNetworkReply::readAll` to get any remaining bytes.

What isn't clear to me is how many times I should call `read` in `readyRead`, how large of a buffer to pass to it, and whether I should call `read` multiple times in one `readyRead` signal - and if more than once, on what condition should I stop calling `read`:

```
connect(reply, &NetworkReply::readyRead, [file] {
    while (???) {
       file.write(reply->read(???));
    }
});
```

Is `read` guaranteed not to block (and hence block the UI event loop)?

(Also unclear is error checking.  What if there is a network error of file io error in that loop?)

(Also, is there a higher level class that will take care of this for me?)

Comment: from what I understand is that when readyread is emited, this means the data is ready on memory and you can read it freely. This read is ofc blocking the main thread, but reading from memory should not noticeable.
In your case the ready read should be called multiple times, so using the while inside ready read slot should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to call `readAll` in response to `readyRead`.  `readAll` will return all the bytes currently available in memory (it doesn't block until the file is completed):

```
connect(reply, &NetworkReply::readyRead, [file] {
    file.write(reply->readAll());
});
```